# To what extent should ethics questions be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Technologists have an irritating habit of ignoring ethical concerns, the allure of shiny things being stronger.

> "Once the rockets are up, who cares where they come down?
> That's not my department!" says Wernher von Braun.

— *Wernher von Braun*, by Tom Lehrer, via [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wernher_von_Braun)

In the all-too-common extreme, people try *quite hard* to use shiny things to exploit and kill people, or funnel wealth into their own pockets: to ‘win’, in other words.

> “Why, with your radio boat—loaded with dynamite—we would have any enemy navy in the world at the bottom in no time,” exclaimed an admiral who saw the demonstration.
>
> “With this principle,” replied Nikola Tesla more prophetically than he knew, “you may live to see man-made horrors beyond your comprehension.”

— *Ahead of His Time*, by Dick Holdsworth, via [Quote Investigator](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2016/08/22/beyond/)

It's tempting to say that all questions to do with ethics are out of scope. And indeed:

- Questions about the *nature of ethics* are clearly off-topic; some belong on [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).
- Questions asking for judgement calls on specific cases are likely to be of limited usefulness, so aren't a great fit for the Stack Exchange format.
- Questions seeking people's *personal opinions* are [bad subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Is there any room for questions about ethics on this site?

Comment: Ethics are on-topic for [ai.se].

Answer (score 4):

I'm finding it challenging to think up many ethics-related questions which are plausibly on-topic, but there seems to be some possibilities:

- Do Bard and ChatGPT have different ethical boundaries?
- What are some examples of [TruthGPT](https://truthgpt.one/) answers to questions ChatGPT refuses to answer due to ethical concerns?
- Is it possible to get ChatGPT to stop highlighting ethical concerns in almost every response?
- Is there a way to measure how ethical a GenAI is?
- What "unethical" behaviors can get a user banned from using ChatGPT?
- Has OpenAI explained why ChatGPT refuses to act as a therapist?
- Does ChatGPT refuse to answer different questions depending on which country it thinks I'm in?

(And replace ChatGPT with whatever GenAI.)

I think the OP has pretty much pinpointed the problems with ethics questions: opinions, judgement calls, philosophical points.  Such questions are either not great at Stack Exchange, and/or aren't really what we're going for at GenAI.SE.  However, I feel the above questions are answerable with evidence, documentation, or experience.  Maybe there's some room for ethics questions, even if most are best considered off-topic.

Comment: Only the fourth question is about ethics.

Comment: I agree that these questions are good candidates for in-scope GenAI questions, but like @wizzwizz4, I don't think they are about the "ethical concerns" of generative AI and its use.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think that questions about the ethics of using or providing generative AI are off-topic. I'm not suggesting that they should be ignored, only that they are not a good fit for applied-technology SE sites like GenAI.

There is a good post about [whether ethics questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345606/can-i-ask-programming-ethics-questions-on-stack-overflow). While GenAI doesn't have to follow the same guidelines, pretty much everything in the top-voted answers to that question applies to generative AI.

A lot of ethics questions are really legal questions in disguise or have legal aspects to their answers. And I think questions about the legalities of generative AI are definitely off-topic.

Comment: We aren't really a technology site. Questions going too much into the technology side of things are (currently) considered off-topic. Unlike programming, where a library of APIs and techniques ([so]) or methodologies ([programmers.se]) makes sense as a standalone topic, ethics are a _huge_ and _fundamental_ part of GenAI. These things aren't “do X” tools. Many cannot be _used_ as “do X” tools.

Comment: Where we have “really legal questions in disguise”, then – if they're off-topic – we can close them as off-topic. Imo, this shouldn't affect whether we consider an entirely different class of questions as on-topic or not.

Comment: GenAI is very much an applied technology site. While the scope may have expanded some, the core is still about applying a set of technologies (generative AI) to produce/transform content. In that manner, it shares a lot with other applied technology sites, like Stack Overflow. SO is much more than a _library of APIs and techniques, and generally has a larger scope than GenAI. Ethics are huge and fundamental part of nearly all applied technologies, especially software development. That still doesn't make ethical questions a good fit for SE.

Comment: It's about applying a set of technologies to produce/transform _things that humans assign meaning to_. That makes it qualitatively different to the other technology sites. (Consider the nature of the questions on-topic here but off-topic on [ai.se].)

Answer (score -2):

Questions about “the ethics of X” (for on-topic X) should be on-topic. Most questions about ethics hinge on two things:

- The actual facts of the matter.
- How important these are, relative to each other, in determining whether conduct is moral.

The former requires specialist knowledge that this community would be well-equipped to provide, and that [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) would be unlikely to get right. The latter is off-topic.

Very few of these questions are new and exciting ethical frontiers: most of them are pretty settled. Take, for example, academic ethics, which is largely based around maintaining a trustable chain of provenance.

- Only claim your own work as your own.
- If you rely on, or are influenced by, prior work (including your own prior work), cite it.
- Do not attempt to misrepresent your credentials, or the credentials of others, nor attempt to gain the benefit of another's approval by deception.
- Do peer review, and double-check that you're not citing a non-peer-reviewed source for anything important.
- et cetera

Questions about academic ethics – well, in *this* case, many of them would be more appropriate for [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), but some questions would be best-answered by GenAI experts:

- How can I rewrite my paper to be more [formal / concise / clear / …]?

  - Note that ChatGPT does not meet academic integrity standards.
- When may I use generated images for X research?
- Can I use a chatbot instead of humans [for my psychology research](https://www.science.org/content/article/can-ai-chatbots-replace-human-subjects-behavioral-experiments)?

Likewise, medical ethics (e.g. questions on automating patient interaction), journalistic ethics… These questions can be answered by reference to well-known ethical standards – the codes of practice of specific organisations, say – with the core of the answer focusing on the facts about GenAI needed to answer the question. A good answer might provide enough information to make an ethical determination under *multiple* different ethical standards, though it wouldn't necessarily *need* to.