# Are questions about the wider GenAI world on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

GenAI is quite hypey at the moment, with a few organisations having a *significant* impact on it. [Rebecca J. Stones](/users/26/rebecca-j-stones) gave [a few example questions about the topic of ethics](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14/10):

> - What "unethical" behaviors can get a user banned from using ChatGPT?
> - Has OpenAI explained why ChatGPT refuses to act as a therapist?
> - Does ChatGPT refuse to answer different questions depending on which country it thinks I'm in?
>
> (And replace ChatGPT with whatever GenAI.)

These are fundamentally questions about *a company*, not about GenAI itself. And yet, these questions seem (to me, at least) straightforwardly on-topic.

Here are some more, to test the waters:

- What are OpenAI's plans for GPT 5?
- Why is OpenAI in trouble with EU regulators?
- Will OpenAI cease operating in the EU?
- What is OpenAI's relationship to TESCREAL?
- Who is " petertodd" in real life?
- What motivated editorial decisions in Stable Diffusion's training dataset?
- Under what circumstances might ChatGPT become unavailable?

---

More-specific scope discussions:

- [Are questions about GenAI-related history on-topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/10)

Answer (score 4):

*Please ignore my staff badge and mod diamond in this answer as this is not an official position of SE.*

Yes.

My reasoning is that because it's so hype-oriented, question-askers will wonder these things anyway to help get to their answers and inform their use of these tools. Since this site is essentially centered around using these tools, understanding the why in some of these questions helps inform their choice of what they use and possibly how they might use them.

Comment: Do you have opinions on the examples in the question?

Comment: For the example questions I think 1, 6, and 7 would be on topic. Though 1, would inevitably be outdated and 6 could open up a can of ethics concerns. 2 & 3 seem like they would be better suited elsewhere, maybe law.se or politics.se. 4 &5 are troll attempts and I would close them out right.

Comment: 5 was a joke, yeah (though it's [close to a reasonable question](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/jkY6QdCfAXHJk3kea/the-petertodd-phenomenon)), but why do you say 4 is a troll attempt? It seems to me quite similar to the other questions on the list.

Comment: Whenever I have encountered TESCREAL stuff, I feel like it comes off as conspiratorial. I may be uneducated here and have not yet dived down deep enough, though.

Comment: TESCREAL was coined by academics _primarily_ in order to discuss the broader ideological context in which it exists. [Here's a Twitter thread by a coauthor of the originating article](https://nitter.1d4.us/xriskology/status/1635313838508883968).

Comment: It's not particularly conspiratorial. I used to hang around with the LessWrong crowd a lot (and still kinda do, if I'm being honest): every TESCREAL-style criticism I've seen of them is accurate. The whole concept of "AI alignment" comes from there. etc etc.

Comment: This is a good example of why we _downvote_ questions we think are mere trolling, rather than close-voting (_especially_ if we have diamonds). A good answer might appear, and reveal that the question _did_ actually have merit – but we'd never get that opportunity if the question were hammered shut.

Comment: Back to the main topic: This is the can of worms that we open by allowing such questions. Perhaps there's some line we can draw to allow some, but not others, but nothing comes to mind just at the moment. (Other than "don't ask questions that might be difficult for GenAI practitioners"… but I don't think that's ethical.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I gave this some more thought, and I think the limtus test on this should be that they are on topic as long as it's in some way related to the use of the tools. This framework would say that 1, 6, and 7 are all on topic because they, in some way, might inform the practical use of a tool. Questions 2, 3, and 4 are strictly related to the organization and not the tool, 5 still would remain off topic because it has nothing to do with the use of the tools.

Comment: 3, 2, 4 and 5 (in order of pertinent to nearly-irrelevant) could impact somebody's choice of which tools to use / invest in, which informs the practical use of the tool – because ChatGPT is not a piece of software you can run, but a proprietary SaaSS, so when it's no longer available, it's no longer available. (Devil's advocating aside, 5 should _definitely_ be off-topic.)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I guess I am seeing 2,3, and 4 as still off-topic because its not about the user of the tool, but about possible associated questions, and I just don't think those should be on topic. However, I don't see great fits for those questions elsewhere on the network either.

Comment: That seems well-thought-out, but it's quite different to your answer. Could you either edit, or (perhaps better) write it up as a separate answer, please?

Answer (score 4):

## Divide and Conquer!

I think we should categorize those questions before deciding if they are on-topic so that it becomes useful information for future reference. After categorization, we can now decide if we want to keep the category as on-topic or not. Let's look at all of the example questions from my perspective (yours may be different) as a step 1.

1. What are OpenAI's plans for GPT 5?

This may be about a specific GenAI tool's plan. So, it can be categorized as `future plan of GenAI tool`.

2. Why is OpenAI in trouble with EU regulators?

This maybe about `legal issue`. I don't know much about it.

3. Will OpenAI cease operating in the EU?

This is about `(GenAI) organization's plan`.

4. What is OpenAI's relationship to TESCREAL?

This is about `(GenAI) organization's relationship`.

5. Who is " petertodd" in real life?

This is really asking about a `person`.

6. What motivated editorial decisions in Stable Diffusion's training
   dataset?

I don't really understand the question. I'm so sorry. No comment on this one from me.

7. Under what circumstances might ChatGPT become unavailable?

This might be about `GenAI tool's availability`.

Now that the questions are categorized we can then analyze each individual category to see if it fits the site that we are building, and this should be a collective agreement. Each of them can be and is worth a question on Meta on its own. Let's see my point of view.

**Asking about future plans for GenAI tool(s)**

I think this kind of questions will only have 2 outcomes. 1. No information from the owner of the tool; so, no answer. 2. The owner of the tool already published the information somewhere in the internet; so, the answer will either be a link-only answer to that specific site, or a rewrite of such announcement. Therefore, I think this one should be off-topic because it looks like it is providing very little benefit while the asker can just google it.

**Asking about legal issue**

Straight away off-topic. No doubt.

**Asking about (GenAI) organization's plan**

This is really about the organization, it just relates to GenAI because it made the tool. If the plan has nothing related to GenAI then it is going to off-topic no matter the organization. However, if the plan relates to GenAI tool then see *1. Asking about future plans for GenAI tool(s)* above.

**Asking about (GenAI) organization's relationship**

This should be off-topic. Organizational relationship has nothing to do with GenAI tools.

**Asking about person/people**

Really? Even if the they have something related to GenAI, I don't think it should be on-topic here. For example, asking who is "holydragon" in real life? Even if I am the one who posted this answer and related directly in GenAI.SE as a user, this information has very little benefit to the site. Off-topic straight away.

**Asking about GenAI tool's availability**

I can see why this one being on-topic. Some tools may have constraints that it will only be available on some conditions. This information is useful for those people to use the tool. Even people who do not use the tool will likely benefit from it one way or another.

======

**Update: more example questions**

8. What "unethical" behaviors can get a user banned from using ChatGPT?

I think this is about `GenAI tool's policy`.

9. Has OpenAI explained why ChatGPT refuses to act as a therapist?

This is about `GenAI tool's history`.

10. Does ChatGPT refuse to answer different questions depending on which country it thinks I'm in?

This might be about `GenAI tool's behavior`.

**Asking about GenAI tool's policy**

Each GenAI tool has different set of policies. Some are difficult to understand or even difficult to find the information. I think it is a good idea to let this topic be asked on the site. Even though the answer may just easily refer to the site with all of the policy in it for the asker to read, it sometimes depends on individual interpretation.

**Asking about GenAI tool's history**

[Are questions about GenAI-related history on-topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/are-questions-about-genai-related-history-on-topic)

**Asking about GenAI tool's behavior**

I think understanding GenAI tool's behavior is important to how we design prompts for it. IMO, it should be on-topic.

Comment: Several examples are specific to OpenAI. Grouping them are company-specific questions. IIRC Meta Stack Exchange for this kind of question. Again IIRC, it says that SO and SE sites are not "customer service" / "PR" so such questions should not be allowed.

Comment: Here is [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/1359324)

Comment: 2 _might_ be a legal question, but in this case, it happens to be more of a news question, easily answerable by reference to what the regulators say. (We don't have to assess the _validity_ of the regulators' argument to answer “why is OpenAI in trouble with them?”.) Other than that, I like this categorisation scheme: it gives a good reason for 4 to be off-topic, without throwing 3 out as well.

Comment: @Wicket «Unfortunately, there is (usually) no site in the network for your question, for the simple reason that it can only be answered _if you work for that company_.» If we apply this logic to this site, a _large_ portion of our ChatGPT-related questions asked so far are off-topic.

Comment: There is no shame in closing a lot of questions when there are good reasons to do so. Doing it as early as possible is better because posts might attract similar posts. Unfortunately, currently, there is an ongoing moderation strike, so many users, including me, are not flagging / voting to close.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Done. See the updated answer. Please be aware that it is just only my opinion. I would like to see others' opinions as well.

Answer (score 2):

I very much lean towards "on-topic" on this matter, but we need to watch out for "speculation requests".

We need to balance a bunch of concerns here, but most importantly is identifying where the interest and expertise lies.

- **Are genAI users typically interested in genAI companies**, their policies, how they interact with other companies, strategic decisions, press releases, official statements and leaks, their finances, hardware and software, and how their genAIs are evolving?

  I feel this is a *strong yes*.  I think most people here are interested in these topics.  (I, for one, want to ask such questions.)
- **Are these question able to help users of genAI?**

  To some degree, yes, understanding business and genAI design decisions can help users use genAI (e.g. deciding which genAIs to familiarize oneself with, or understanding why ChatGPT apologizes so much).  But maybe most of the time they're of fairly academic interest.
- **Do we have expertise?**

  I'm guessing the users here are probably at least as familiar with such topics as any other group (barring some genAI journalist, maybe).
- **Can/will these questions be answered in a meaningful way**, especially with reliable citations, or will they be met with pointless speculation?

  The potential for "speculation requests" seems to be where the problems lie.  But maybe "speculation requests" should be off-topic, and not the rest.
- **Will such questions attract people to the site?**

  I feel this is also a *strong yes*.  This is the kind of thing people find on Google, and it would be great if they found GenAI.SE that way.  It's also the kind of thing people share on Reddit.

---

For the given questions

- What are OpenAI's plans for GPT 5?

  In a sense this is "future speculation".  Apparently the answer is [still no plans](https://techcrunch.com/2023/06/07/openai-gpt5-sam-altman/).

  I give you my answer [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39645/8099) regarding the Chinese HSK reform as an example to how such a question might be answered: updated as new information is brought to light.  I note I got the [Booster badge](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster?userid=8099) for sharing it on Reddit.
- Why is OpenAI in trouble with EU regulators?

  This sounds concretely answerable with links to news articles.  At the same time, it may touch on legal topics, and may be easily answerable through Google.  It depends on the body of the question.
- Will OpenAI cease operating in the EU?

  It should be rephrased to something like "As of [date], has OpenAI indicated they will cease operating in the EU?" which asks for evidence over speculation.
- What is OpenAI's relationship to TESCREAL?

  (I don't know what TESCREAL is.  I don't have anything meaningful to say here.)
- Who is " petertodd" in real life?

  (Oh, this is [something else entirely](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/jkY6QdCfAXHJk3kea/the-petertodd-phenomenon).  Why phrase it like this?)
- What motivated editorial decisions in Stable Diffusion's training dataset?

  Seems a bit unspecific to me.  If the body pointed to a specific decision, it would be better.  Or if it asked for the overarching motivation behind editorial decisions in general, it might work too.
- Under what circumstances might ChatGPT become unavailable?

  Worldwide, or in, say, Italy?  Are we talking in the next few months, or in the next 10 years?  This seems like a request for speculation.  But, as always, the body of the question might change everything.

---

And for questions I might think about asking:

- Has Reddit shown any indication they're intending to integrate genAI?
- Is it known why Apple has decided to implement Apple GPT, while previously shying away from the genAI race?
- How is genAI relevant to Dell, which focuses more on hardware?
- Is NVIDIA intending to make GPUs specifically for genAI?
- When did Stack Exchange first indicate their intentions to integrate genAI features?
- How much can companies make from selling their data to train genAIs?
- Are most genAIs just a front-end, and the actual legwork done by a few ultra-trained genAIs?
- What military applications does genAI have?
- Which governments have publicly announced they are implementing their own genAI?
- How has Twitter/X's policy towards AI-generated tweets evolved since the release of ChatGPT?

Oh, and I did ask one:

- [Is there a way to gauge how environmentally (un)friendly popular genAIs are?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/151/26)

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned that expanding the site's scope to include the entire realm of GenAI could result in an excessive focus on the high points of the hype rollercoaster, which may leave community members feeling bored during the low points.

This might not be a real problem if the **core community** stays together long-term and if the GenAI hype rollercoaster doesn't have a long low plain during the following six months (ref. [Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange! ("Limited Private Beta")](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/12)).

Comment: Do you have opinions on the examples in the question?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 There are too many. I suggest you post more specific questions.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about: if there's a better boundary to draw that allows some of the questions but not others. I wouldn't know what constitutes “more specific questions” (though it will be obvious in retrospect, I'm sure).

Comment: It might take me a long time to find a way to split the question in a helpful way. Please stay tunned.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 holydragon beat me: -> https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/12. I added there a couple of comments.