# How will this site handle questions that could be considered as helping perform unethical actions?

Tags: discussion

[What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/45) mentions prohibitions on questions about illegal or dangerous activities. Of course these are problematic terms because "legality" varies, and in some places it is illegal to have gay sex, criticize the government, or chew gum, and "dangerous" similarly has no clear definition or meaning.

What about questions about designing prompts to cheat on homework without detection, or to not let your coworkers know you aren't personally writing the code or documents you present as your own, or to transform a benign social media image into something pornographic, or to effectively mimic the speech of a politician to create an embarrassing or misleading video?

If these sorts of questions are not allowed, what guidelines should be used to identify them and distinguish them among more legitimate requests?

Comment: They are not allowed. That will be an SE policy for legal reasons. We are crafting that answer still and will probably wrap it into one question to cover some of the similar questions.

Comment: @SpencerG How will you determine what is and isn't ethical? What about when ethical norms vary by country?

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike Please clarify what you mean by "ethical," as this term has different meanings in different contexts / realms. I.E. "ethical" might not be the same in a higher management meeting as in a law court or an Academic setting, and even in an Academics setting; the meaning might vary if there are people from different disciplines like philosophy, theology, etc. This clarification is important because it relates to the information provided in the question itself.

Comment: Simply put we don't want the liability teaching people how to use these tools in ways they have expressly defined as not intended for. So anything that falls under jailbreaking these tools. Some of the points you mentioned do, so those would be firmly off-topic. For the remainder,  like cheating on homework or creating embarrassing videos I imagine we all agree we don't want to help with those things and they would just fall under site policy.

Comment: @Wicket I think that falls more in the scope of an answer. In the question I've just provided some possible examples/areas of concern. I'll rephrase it a bit to clarify.

Comment: @SpencerG I'm happy to hear it's not something you want, but how do we identify what these tools are not intended for? Certainly some people do think the things I listed are intended uses of these tools, and specific GenAI sites already exist that are tailored to exactly some of the examples I gave. People are right now already using these tools to do their work without disclosing to their coworkers, leading to questions on other SE sites about how to handle that behavior. I don't think the examples I gave necessarily fall under "jailbreaking" as it's usually used.

Answer (score 7):

Questions **blatantly** looking for help for doing criminal acts, violating applicable laws, doing academic cheating, doing fraud, causing damage to things / harm to people should be flagged as

> **Rude or abusive**
> A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

When it is appropriate to provide context, instead flag it for moderation attention:

> **In need of moderator intervention**
> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

If you aren't sure that the question is blatantly looking for help "to cause harm", look at this place, GenAI SE Meta to see if there is already a related discussion or guidance. You might post a question or flag the post for moderation attention.

---

The terms "ethical" and "unethical" are used in various ways and can be subjective. People often use these terms to describe something as wrong or immoral, even if they can't explain why. They may simply argue that it's common sense.

Please don't flag "unethical" posts for moderation attention if you can't explain why something is wrong, immoral, or against the Code of Conduct or relevant norms. Still, you might talk about the case as something "suspicious" while this is relevant to keep the site helpful, healthy and safe.

Comment: If you can provide context publicly, post that context as a comment then R&A flag. Mod flags _have to_ be handled by a moderator, but red flags (spam, R&A) take effect automatically once enough sufficiently-privileged users have flagged it.

Answer (score 4):

If it were a matter of everyone agreeing on "this is ethical" and "this is unethical", then we know what to do; we've been doing it for years.  That's the easy part.

The problem is that there's myriad topics which one person could reasonably consider as ethical, and another could reasonably consider as unethical (oh, and what is and isn't ethical is evolving).

- Can ChatGPT pretend to be my deceased wife?  I miss her so much.
- Could AI generate an infographic showing the evils of Islam?
- How can I influence the 2024 US presidential election using AI?
- How can I generate AI hentai that satisfies my ultra-specific sexual fantasy (details included)?
- Can AI edit this photograph to make it look like Rhianna is standing behind me?
- Which ChatGPT alternatives are not "woke"?
- How can I trick ChatGPT into swearing?

(There are people who consider e.g. ChatGPT's output to be plagiarism, so they might consider every question about ChatGPT as unethical.)

So the question is: ***who are the "ethical" gatekeepers?***  Who gets to decide what is or isn't ethical?

Since...

- the site could end up discussing virtually any topic ("How can I do XYZ with GenAI?");
- the plurality of opinions users will have (your "ethical dilemma" = my "free speech");
- sites work better if users are not squandered constantly debating;
- many ethically borderline questions are going to be one-offs;
- it's best not to leave it up to just a small number of people (this leads to arguments; they may not know the ins and outs of every topic);
- there are mental health concerns if ethically borderline questions were to arise in large numbers;

**I suggest having a "closed for ethical concerns" custom close reason**.  Five people voting to close for ethical reasons sends a different message than just one moderator (flags are generally invisible to users).

---

As a "first draft" custom close reason, maybe something like this would work:

**Close dialog option**

Brief description:

> Ethically problematic.

Usage guidance:

> The question makes users feel uncomfortable for some ethics-related reason, such as those listed in the [faq].

**Post notices**

Close description:

> This question is considered to have ethical concerns making it unsuitable for the site.  It is not currently accepting answers.

Post owner guidance:

> There are many possible ethical concerns that could arise in questions; some are listed in the [faq].  Please consult the comments or ask on [meta] if the close reasons need clarifying.  If possible, consider [edit]ing the question to remedy these concerns.

Public guidance:

> Aside from a few reasons enumerated in the [faq], decisions to close questions for ethical concerns are often subjective.  Consider voting to reopen if you disagree with the decision to close.

(It seems like it would help to enumerate major ethically problematic close reasons in the faq.)

Comment: For a topic where there'll be a wide spectrum of opinions (including "every question about ChatGPT as unethical"), I'm not certain that a fixed threshold of 5 people would scale properly by how much visibility the question gets. Maybe if there was some way for it to be a percentage of "should be closed" vs "shouldn't be closed"?

Comment: Once you feel comfortable doing it, please post the custom close reason suggestion as a question. Please also consider the possibility of using a custom post notice.

Comment: I have added an [answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/70/12) mentioning the custom post notice as part of being considered in the GenAI community workings to handle questions having ethical concerns.

Comment: What's considered unethical varies by context and field: in many cases, a consensus already exists. (If we [allowed ethical questions on this site](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/10), we'd have immediate access to that context.)

Answer (score -2):

I agree with most of what is said in [Rebecca's answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/66/12), but I'm not sure that the custom close reason should be used without a properly established working.

Before closing a question due to ethical concerns, there should be a proper discussion in GenAI Meta. In the meantime, questions having this kind of concern should show a posted notice with a custom message.

In World Building, something like this has been done to remind answerers of the quality standards for specific questions. Ref. [Hard-science reminder on answering?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3716)

Comment: It's easy to re-open questions. There's no problem with pre-emptive closure, other than making questions ineligible for the HNQ (which is probably for the best, with questions like that).